# When someone enters their information onto the form (Contact 7 Form), I am not getting notified in my email

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using Contact 7 Form to gather client leads on my [website](https://cincoranchtreepros.com).

https://cincoranchtreepros.com

However, when someone enters their information onto the form (Contact 7 Form), I am not getting notified in my email.

On the Form:

```
[text* Name placeholder"Name"] 

[text* Email placeholder"Email"] 

[text* Phone placeholder"Phone"] 

[text* Zipcode placeholder"Zipcode"] 

[text* Service placeholder"Service"] 

[submit "GET YOUR FREE QUOTE"]
```

On the Mail:

Message Body:

Submission Info:

Name: [Name]

Email: [Email]

Phone: [Phone]

Zipcode: [Zipcode]

Service: [Service]

^^^ This is the part that I'm not sure what to do. Any help on code would be so greatly appreciated! I am not getting notified.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUpxY.png)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAyvh.png)

I tried to play around with it but I am very noob at coding.

Comment: Your email address in the form is a text field, and not an email field.  This is not a coding issue, this is a using a wordpress plugin issue, which really is offtopic for stackoverflow.  `[text* Email placeholder"Email"] ` should be `[email* Email placeholder"Email"]`

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be related to the email settings or the way you have set up the mail template. Let's go through the steps to troubleshoot the issue:

Step 1: Check Email Settings
Make sure you have correctly configured the email settings in the Contact Form 7 plugin. To do this, go to your WordPress dashboard, then navigate to "Contact" -> "Contact Forms." Select the form you're using, and then click on the "Mail" tab.

In the "To" field, enter the email address where you want to receive the notifications. For example, if you want to receive emails at "youremail@example.com," enter that email address in the "To" field.

Step 2: Verify Mail Template
It seems like you already have a mail template set up. The mail template you provided looks fine, but you might want to include some additional formatting and styling to make it more readable. I'll provide you with an improved version of the template:

```
Message Body:

Submission Info:
    
Name: [your-name]
Email: [your-email]
Phone: [your-phone]
Zipcode: [your-zipcode]
Service: [your-service]
```

Step 3: Check Server Mail Configuration (Advanced)
If the above steps don't work, it's possible that there might be issues with your server's mail configuration. In such cases, you might need to use a plugin like WP Mail SMTP, which allows you to configure the email settings and use a third-party email service to send emails.

Remember, debugging email issues can sometimes be complex, especially if server settings are involved. If you find that you're still not receiving emails, you might want to reach out to your hosting provider for assistance.

Once you've gone through these steps, let me know if you're still facing any issues, and I'll do my best to assist you further!

Comment: Thanks for answering Zeyad.

However, it looks like i'm getting this answer when i'm inputting [your-name] and the others : Invalid mailbox syntax is used in the Message Body field.

It might be that the syntax is incorrect